# How to install 'Google play services' over an android phone samsung galaxy Y S5306 using my PC?

Tags: google-play-store

How to install 'Google play services' over an android phone samsung galaxy Y S5360 using my PC? Will it require kies?I am facing the similar issue as faced by this gentleman ([Can't install Google Play Services](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42335/cant-install-google-play-services/42966#42966?newreg=dae7b3f79b134606ae28619482bc84e0)). The resolution has been provided in the link but I dont know how to install apps over my phone via a PC. Pls

Answer (score 2):

Open your browser and log-in to https://play.google.com/ using your Google account. Then, open this link on your browser: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms

It might ask you to open the link in Google Play. Don't do it. Choose to open the browser instead. You should see an Install button in the page. Click it, and the app will be pushed to your phone.

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

If installing it directly from the play store doesn't work for you you can try downloading the file from other websites that host it and then transferring it to your phone using a USB cable.

http://www.xda-developers.com/android/apk-compendium-google-play-services-4-4-52-for-all-densities-and-the-rest-of-this-weeks-updates/

Here's a link to the latest version.